# I wanted to apply for a school as soon as I had settled/settled down here

Tags: grammar

Hello: I am not sure if it's grammatically correct say "I wanted to apply for a school as soon as I had settled down here". Or maybe it's better to say "I wanted to apply for a school as soon as I settled down here"? Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I searched the Internet and found the following sentences:

1. I wanted to go back as soon as I left.
2. I wanted to sleep as soon as I got home
3. I wanted to create comics as soon as a I learned humans were behind them
4. As soon as I had break points I wanted to take them.
5. As soon as it had finished, I wanted to hear it again.

Only number 5 has a different structure, so I would go with:

I wanted to apply for a school as soon as I settled down here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations!

Answer (score -1):

Most probably,

> I wanted to apply for a school as soon as I would settle down here

If the plan ("wanted to apply") occurred before settling, which is probably the scenario you mean.  The sequence of events would be "want to settle then apply" - "settle" - "apply". Note this doesn't imply you actually settled (though that could be inferred from other parts of context).

The variant of

> "I wanted to apply for a school as soon as I settled down here"

would mean you first settled, and right after that got the persistent, but
not necessarily realized idea of applying for school. The prior interpretation is also possible, except the act of settling is confirmed done.

> "I applied for a school as soon as I had settled down here, as planned."

This is a sequence of completed events. Wanting something isn't really an event, just a state, so the 'had settled' as 'event prior to current' doesn't quite fit.